# ReactJS: Reset the display of the placeholder inside a select

Tags: reactjs, jsx

After choosing an option in my Select (using `react-select`), I use the  "onChange" callback prop to do something using the value chosen. I would thei like to display the initial placeholder in the select instead of the option selected by the user.

I tried to add a ref on the select and give the select.value a null value but nothing happened.

```
addTravellers(event){
    this.setState({travellers : this.state.travellers.concat(event.value)},()=>this.checkPax(this.state.travellers));
  }

<Select 
        options={ages}
        placeholder={"my placeholder"}
        className={s.selector}
        onChange={(e) => this.addTravellers(e)}
        ref={this.refSelect}
        />
```

The result I would like is after `addTravellers()` is called, the select should display the placeholder instead of the last selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `onChange` callback to be fired when the user selects an option however you want the placeholder to remain visible regardless of user selection - in that case a simple solution would be to force  `null` as the `value` prop of `<Select />` which will cause the placeholder to remain visible after option selection occurs:

```
<Select 
    options={ages}
    placeholder={"my placeholder"}
    className={s.selector}
    onChange={(e) => this.addTravellers(e)}
    value={ null } /* <-- add this */
    /* ref={this.refSelect} Not needed */
    />
```